# tns test android hangs after synced to device

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, nativescript

I'm currently trying to setup unit testing on my nativescript project. I'm using mocha with chai as my testing framework and have run `tns test init` all ok.

When I run `tns test android` every runs ok and the emulator starts. However, after it has synced the application to my emulator, which also starts ok, it hangs at:

```
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://***.***.**.*:9876/context.json
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://***.***.*.**:9876/context.json
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://127.0.0.1:9876/context.json
```

I've tried a few different things, on being running `tns test android --debug-brk` to see where it fails. This says that  `Error: Could not find device by specified identifier 'undefined'` but the emulator is running fine as the command had started it up and I can see the emulator using `tns device`.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `tns test android --device 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `Android Manifest` to `<application` file seems to have resolved the issue of not finding the Karma server.

See https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4182

I am using nativescript version `4.2.0` so the latest version may have fixed this.